# How to I sum up my data in 4 rows?

Tags: sql-server

```
Select 
    AvHours.LineNumber,
    (SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS))) AS Throughput,
    SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS) AS [Lost Time], 
    (SUM(cast(ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS AS decimal(10,1))) * 100) / (cast(AvHours.AvailableHRS AS decimal(10,1))) AS [%DownTime],
    SUM(SProd.PoundsMade) AS [Pounds Made],
    (SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS))) *  SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS) AS [Pounds Lost]
FROM rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs AvHours
    inner join rpt_Line_Shift_Prod SProd on 
        AvHours.LineNumber=SProd.LineNumber AND AvHours.Shiftnumber=SProd.Shiftnumber
    inner join rpt_Line_Shift_ProdDownTime ProdDtime on 
        (AvHours.LineNumber=ProdDtime.LineNumber AND AvHours.Shiftnumber=ProdDtime.Shiftnumber)
GROUP BY AvHours.LineNumber,SProd.PoundsMade,AvHours.AvailableHRS
ORDER BY AvHours.LineNumber
```

The query above gives the following result set:

```
Line#,Throughput,Lost Time, %downtime,Pounds Made,Pounds Lost   

1   53  49  27.222222   97538   2597
1   44  39  20.312500   116229  1716
1   47  40  22.222222   92190   1880
1   55  31  16.145833   133215  1705
1   111 49  27.222222   204442  5439
1   13  31  16.145833   33540   403
1   86  49  27.222222   159432  4214
1   81  31  16.145833   197145  2511
1   74  40  22.222222   146202  2960
1   63  49  27.222222   115920  3087
1   76  39  20.312500   199172  2964
2   64  40  22.222222   126028  2560
2   149 49  27.222222   273966  7301
2   35  39  20.312500   92616   1365
3   49  39  20.312500   129591  1911
3   65  40  22.222222   129248  2600
3   84  39  20.312500   219997  3276
4   95  31  16.145833   229485  2945
4   76  40  22.222222   149996  3040
4   94  31  16.145833   228375  2914
4   99  39  20.312500   259794  3861
```

What I actually want is just 4 lines (`Line#` = 1,2,3 or 4) and all the other fields summed.

I'm not sure how to do it. Can anybody help?

Comment: Sentence structure changed to clarify question

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of PoundsMade and AvailableHrs in your group by.  It sounds like you only want to group by the Linenumber.

Comment: I tried that its giving me an error.                                                              "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.PoundsMade' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.AvailableHRS' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: That's true.  Every field that isn't in the `GROUP BY` has to be wrapped inside an aggregate.  For example - `SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS)))` could perhaps be `SUM(SProd.PoundsMade) / (SUM(AvHours.AvailableHRS) - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS)))`.  There are other columns you may have to update as well.  Check to see if this formula works for your data.

Comment: I tried that as well but again its giving me an error....:(                                                     Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your sql as a nested table and then group by the line number 
like the sql below.

`Select LineNumber, Sum(Throughput), Sum([Lost Time]), Sum([%DownTime]), Sum([Pounds Made]), Sum([Pounds Lost])
From
(Select 
    AvHours.LineNumber,
    (SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS))) AS Throughput,
    SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS) AS [Lost Time], 
    (SUM(cast(ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS AS decimal(10,1))) * 100) / (cast(AvHours.AvailableHRS AS decimal(10,1))) AS [%DownTime],
    SUM(SProd.PoundsMade) AS [Pounds Made],
    (SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS))) *  SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS) AS [Pounds Lost]
FROM rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs AvHours
    inner join rpt_Line_Shift_Prod SProd on 
        AvHours.LineNumber=SProd.LineNumber AND AvHours.Shiftnumber=SProd.Shiftnumber
    inner join rpt_Line_Shift_ProdDownTime ProdDtime on 
        (AvHours.LineNumber=ProdDtime.LineNumber AND AvHours.Shiftnumber=ProdDtime.Shiftnumber)
GROUP BY AvHours.LineNumber,SProd.PoundsMade,AvHours.AvailableHRS
) A
Group BY LineNumber
ORDER BY LineNumber`

I dont have a sql server right now to test this out, But let me know if you encounter any issue

*Please mark this as answer if it helped resolving your issue*